# c, i and s commands combined in VIM

Tags: vim, text, syntax, editor

I've been using VIM for a while and it surprises me each time. Under "Building Sentences" section in this [tutorial](https://danielmiessler.com/study/vim/#changing), I saw the combination of commands `cis` and `yip`. I have used Vim quite a while and I am familiar with most commands in Normal Mode. I also know combining the commands in a meaningful way to produce combined actions.

However, the examples I showed above (`cis` and `yip`) totally broke my understanding of VIM command system in normal mode. "c" stands for change, "i" stands for insert and "s" stands for substitute but combined action is different than I would expect. I also went through VIM help files but never saw an example illustrating given usage.

Could someone clarify what's going on ?

Comment: Start here: `:h operator`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

cis

In vim help it is described as follows

```
:help c
```

"Delete {motion} text [into register x] and start insert …"

The next part of the command c**is** refer to the "motion" part. These commands are for text object selection. An explanation on the different types of text object selections can you get here:

```
:help text-objects
```

e.g. for 
*is – "inner sentence", select [count] sentences …*

Analog to the explanation above its the same with yip

```
:help y
```

*"Yank {motion} text [into register x] … "*

And the text selection part y**ip**

*ip – "inner paragraph", select [count] paragraphs (see                                                                                                                                            paragraph) …*

Comment: This is the answer I was looking for because it took :help into consideration. Thanks.

Comment: I often use vip combo in my practice. You should try it;)

Answer (score 3):

In this case i does not stand for Insert and s not for substitute.
cis = change inner sentence.

This is completly logic once you understand the basic principle. Each command is like a sentence, it needs an Verb(Action) and an Noun(Object) and there are modifiers.

So the first button is your action C (Change). Now the following keystrokes will not be actions, until the c action ended (Until an Object is provided, or an invalid sequence is inserted). I (inner) is a modifier here and S the Object (Sentence).

I find this especially usefull for Changing words. if you only press cw on a word, you have to have the cursor on the beginning of the word.
With ciw you can change the whole word regardless of the cursor position (Note if you have / or some other seperators in the word, you maybe need ciW)

Comment: Would be a much better answer if it also mentioned how to find relevant information with :help

Comment: @normadov I agree with you, but luckely alot of other people did this. I thougth it is more important to understand the basic principle. But it will add the help call the next time.

Answer (score 1):

same letter can have different meanings. E.g. `(/{` move to sentences/paragraph back, but `ci( or ci{` means `change in (...)/{...}`.

Same as your `s` case, `s` in normal mode alone, does `delete & start insert`, however in `cis, das` means `sentence`.

`p` case: in normal mode alone, means `paste`, however in `cip, yap ...` means `paragraph`.

```
:h text-objects
```

will show you the concept of text-objects. It is a *must* skill for vim user. ;-)